# How to filter models in django database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Hello i created movies website , this is my `models.py`

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ("A","ACTION"),
    ("D","DRAMA"),
    ("C","COMEDY"),
    ("R",'ROMANCE'),

class Movie(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, 
      title_english = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      descritpion = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to="movies")
      category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,max_length=1)
      language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,max_length=30)
      status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,max_length=2)
      year_of_production = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and this is my `views.py`

```
def home(request):
    user = request.user
    Movies_obj = models.Movie.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request,'index.html',{'user':user,'movies':Movies_obj})
```

in views.py i order last 10 movies , now i want to show only this movies which is DRAMA or Comedy how to filter it ?

Answer (score 1):

Category field has values A or D so you need to filter category field with those values.

```
models.Movie.objects.filter(category__in=['A', 'D']).order_by('-id')[:10]
```